# Google Issue tracking software?

Tags: bug-tracking

What is the issue tracking system used by Google Code to track projects like GWT http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list Chromium http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list etc?

I'd like to know if this bug tracking software is an open source project available for download.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you [create a new project](http://code.google.com/hosting/createProject) on code.google.com, the issue tracker comes with it.  As far as I know, this is a custom issue tracker built for [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/), and according to Wikipedia, the code for Google's issue tracker [isn't open source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems).  They do have [an API for building client applications](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPI) that interact with the Issue Tracker, though. An [open source client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-issue-tracker/) has been written in C#, but I haven't used it, so I can't speak to its functionality or flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

The issue tracking software that was used on Google Code was never open-sourced, as it depended upon many Google-internal systems (eg. BigTable). The site was developed in Python from about August 2005 through to the launch of Google Code in July 2006, by a team of four engineers (including myself).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth mentioning that the Chromium team did a rewrite of the issue tracker, which is a nearly identical drop-in replacement. It's an open-source [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) application called Monorail and it's being used at [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/).

https://chromium.googlesource.com/infra/infra/+/master/appengine/monorail